# Export variable to production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger, ubuntu-12.04

I'm working on a Rails app which uses ports, I'm trying to export it. Here is what i've tried:

config/environment.rb

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Facturas::Application.initialize!
ENV['PORT_NUMBER'] = '12000'
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'gmail.com',
  :user_name            => 'email',
  :password             => '****************',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

also the file on server /etc/environment:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
PORT_NUMBER = "12000"
```

I've tried them separately and together but it does not do the trick, i'm calling the port number in a gem if that helps:

```
port = ENV['PORT_NUMBER'] || find_available_port
```

I'm on ubuntu server, working with apache and passenger.

Comment: Check out this link http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used ENV for similar purposes. Only issue I can guess, if the variable is needed by the gem during its load phase. config/environment.rb gets loaded after gems are loaded. In such a case, it needs to be placed in config/boot.rb towards the top (before bundler loads gems):

```
    require 'rubygems'
    ENV['PORT_NUMBER'] = '12000'
```

For other approach, /etc/environment will get used only when a user logs-in, which is not the case for Apache (which starts as a service in Ubuntu). Try setting ENV in Apache 
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#env_vars_passenger_apps

Comment: Yes! This is how i finally get it to work thank you @Deepak Kumar, i just put the code on the boot.rb and now it's working the way i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [About environment variables](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#about_environment_variables) appendix in the Phusion Passenger manual.